# Flex component like a multi-selectable Accordion?

Tags: apache-flex, accordion

I'm looking for a component like a single-generation treeview that can collapse a section or expand any or all sections, but it would look like an Accordion: headings and canvas "pages".

Obviously, each page would not take up the entire height of the container; they would be fixed height.

Perhaps I am not using the correct terminology (and hence the wrong search terms).

All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Why dont you try making that component yourself, It doesn't sound like any built in components that I know of.

Comment: WindowShade (see bill d below) looks like a good starting place.

I'm trying to wean myself of immediately building stuff myself --

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try a VBox with multiple [WindowShade](http://flexlib.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/flexlib/containers/WindowShade.html) components from the [flexlib](http://code.google.com/p/flexlib/) library, like in this [example](http://flexlib.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/WindowShade/WindowShade_Sample.swf).  You'd need to tweak the styles so it looks more accordian-like though.