# Flex accordion component : open multiple navigationContents at once?

Tags: apache-flex

Is there a way to open multiple navigation contents at the same time with the Accordion in Flex 4.5 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible with the basic `Accordion` component. You'll have to create a custom component to get this kind of functionality.

Based on [bill d's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571341/flex-component-like-a-multi-selectable-accordion/571838#571838) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/571341/275643):

> You could try a VBox with multiple
>   [WindowShade](http://flexlib.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/flexlib/containers/WindowShade.html) components from the
>   [flexlib](http://code.google.com/p/flexlib/) library, like in this
>   [example](http://flexlib.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/WindowShade/WindowShade_Sample.swf).  You'd need to tweak the
>   styles so it looks more accordian-like
>   though.

Comment: yep. the idea took the place well :)